# How to transform this Diffusion equation ?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, transformation, substitution

I have a diffusion equation:

$$ \nabla^2C = \frac{\partial C}{\partial t}$$.

Now I would like to transform this equation into a co-ordiante frame which movies with the unperturbed palaner interface($z=0$ ) with steady state veloity $v_o$, i.e. $z = z -v_0t$.

Can anyone explain how to go about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current variables are the position $\mathbf{x}$ and the time $t$, that will be transformed to $\mathbf{x}'=\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{v}_0 t$ and $t'=t$. According to the chain rule,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial t'}{\partial t} \frac{\partial}{\partial t'} + \frac{\partial x'}{\partial t} \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} + \frac{\partial y'}{\partial t} \frac{\partial}{\partial y'}+ \frac{\partial z'}{\partial t} \frac{\partial}{\partial z'} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t'} + \mathbf{v}_0 \cdot \nabla
$$

Therefore, the equation is now
$$
\nabla^2 C = \frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + \mathbf{v}_0 \cdot \nabla C,
$$
i.e., in the moving frame the diffusion equation takes the form of an advection-diffusion equation. Naturally, using $\mathbf{v}_0=0$ in the equation leads back to the original diffusion equation.